# filter list of partitition

Tags: r, filter, partitioning

i would filter a list like this: `[1] (33,7)(4)(5)(6)(8)`, where return true or false if  in the item there is same element twice, for example:

```
(33,7)(4)(5)(33)FALSE
(33,33)(4)(5)(6) FALSE
```

but element where element near in position 2 and 3, 4 and 5, or 6 and 7 that apperas twice return TRUE,but if the list is of 7 element for example last two element must be different for example:

```
(33,1)(7)(7)(6)  TRUE
(33,1)(7)(6)(5)(5)(9) TRUE
(33,1)(7)(6)(6)  FALSE
(33,1)(1)(9)(6)(7)  FALSE
(33,1)(9)(9)(6)(1)  FALSE
```

Comment: Please add `dput` of your `list`. It is not clear what data structure you have.

Comment: Having trouble understanding the desired output: why is `(33,1)(7)(6)(6)` `TRUE`?

Comment: @nate.edwinton,  it' FALSE

Comment: Shouldn't it be true??

Answer (score 0):

As indicated in the comments, it is still unclear which data structure is at hand. However, this might be of help:

```
# creating a dummy example
lst <- list()
lst[[1]] <- c(33,33)
lst[[2]] <- c(7)
lst[[3]] <- c(4)
lst[[4]] <- c(6)
lst[[5]] <- c(6)
lst[[6]] <- c(1)

# with str(lst) giving:
List of 6
 $ : num [1:2] 33 33
 $ : num 7
 $ : num 4
 $ : num 6
 $ : num 6
 $ : num 1
```

Now we use the function `unique` which removes duplicates and `str(unique(lst))` yields:

```
List of 5
 $ : num [1:2] 33 33
 $ : num 7
 $ : num 4
 $ : num 6
 $ : num 1
```

So now, a simple comparison would do the trick, e.g.

```
length(lst) == length(unique(lst))
# yielding
[1] FALSE
```

And now an example where one has multiple such lists:

```
# creating the example
lst <- lst1 <- lst2 <- list()
# list 1
lst1[[1]] <- c(33,33)
lst1[[2]] <- c(7)
lst1[[3]] <- c(4)
lst1[[4]] <- c(6)
lst1[[5]] <- c(6)
lst1[[6]] <- c(1)
# list 2
lst2[[1]] <- c(33,33)
lst2[[2]] <- c(7)
lst2[[3]] <- c(4)
lst2[[4]] <- c(5)
lst2[[5]] <- c(6)
lst2[[6]] <- c(1)
# lst is a list of two lists
lst <- list(lst1,lst2)

# testing for duplicates
vapply(1:length(lst), 
       function(k) length(lst[[k]]) == length(unique(lst[[k]])),
       logical(1))

# output
[1] FALSE  TRUE
```